# Android espresso click with custom time

Tags: java, android, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

There is `click()` and `longClick()` in `ViewAction` class in androidx.test.espresso.action.

How can I create the same `longClick()` but with custom click time?

Comment: I think what you need is press and hold, take a look at this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052854/5146797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement your custom `Tap` enum similar to `androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap` enum. Declare your custom tap action inside and update this line `long longPressTimeout = (long) (ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() * 1.5f);` with your time.

Then create a custom click action that will use your custom tap.