# When I long click to button, it is always performing and test is frozen

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

I try to write a test case for sending voice from a button. When I long click to voice button in the code, button could not be free and test is paused after 1 minute. How can i solve this problem. I want it to be 10 seconds long.

```
 ViewInteraction ColorImageView = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.voiceSendButton),
                    childAtPosition(
                            allOf(withId(R.id.bottom),
                                    childAtPosition(
                                            withClassName(is("android.widget.LinearLayout")),
                                            2)),
                            2),
                    isDisplayed()));
    ColorImageView.perform(longClick());
```

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052854/11625850 -- I've instituted something similar for having a long press and it works perfectly for me, not entirely sure if it will solve your problem.

Comment: @agoff I implement your methods but not worked. it is inside to **PressAndHoldAction** method but not goes to perform action method so **sMotionEventDownHeldView** always return null